# diagnosing performance of asp.net website / application pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis, application-pool

I am having an issue with a website developed using ASP.Net/C# sometimes taking all the CPU usage   (100%) for an indefinite period of time.  Do you have any ideas / tips how one would go about what could be causing such a resource hog?  The website is still responding, so it is not crashed or something like that.

I'm a bit clueless where to start!

Thanks!

Comment: Issue is in specific page only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DebugDiag is a great place to start: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26798

Comment: Thanks, this tool proved very useful in finding out the currently executing thread on a live server!

Answer (score 1):

Start using Performance Counters on the server. Add the counters for Garbage Collection, Threads usage and see exactly which thread is consuming the CPU.

Also, check out this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2009/04/09/troubleshooting-an-intermittent-net-high-cpu-problem.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I was abroad - Where can I find the 'Thread Usage' performance counter?  This is a live server, which doesn't have a Visual Studio copy installed on it. Ideally I would be able to sample say 4 hours of time, and see which threads where contributing to the CPU usage.  Ideally, I would know the call stack at a point in time, as it would help me a lot in diagnosing the problem.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue in Past. I mainly had problems with `HTML rendering` very slow .
I resolved it by setting the `Trace = true` in page directive and found out the event which were taking time.

Another issue was the `Memory Management`. I was using `Image Classes` and did not `Dispose` them properly. For that I started to use `Dispose()` method and I can have Using statements in the architecture.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection String"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        using (SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

        }
        using (DataTable DT = new DataTable())
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I assume you may have any page where you may be fetching records in excess. You can start to use `Paging`.

The most important point is `Exception Handling`. `Try Catch` block should not be in every layer. It should be in `Presentation Layer` only. Reason being, when exception occurs, it goes back to the calling function directly. So why to write `Try Catch` block and thus `stopping the execution` in each layer

Answer (score 0):

Far the best and easiest starting point is to use performance profiler. Just run it and with a bit of luck you'll have problem fixed in minutes.

Try [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/), it's a quite good one. If you follow the link, there is 10 days free trial and video tutorial.