# What are the consequences of not properly closing a .NET HttpWebRequest?

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, webclient

The question pretty much explains for itself. I would like to know all the consequences of leaving a Http request opened, like:

- resources consumed on client and server
- thread pool or ServicePoint default limits
- is there any default timeout?

Properly closing would be inside a using statement. A bad example could be:

```
var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.ToString()); 

WebResponse myWebResponse = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

var readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, readEncoding); 
response = readStream.ReadToEnd(); 

//if an error occurs, the close statements will not be executed!!!

readStream.Close(); 
myWebResponse.Close();
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is "leaving a request opened"? What is "properly closing"? Can you show relevant code illustrating what you mean? Do you know how HTTP requests work?

Comment: @CodeCaster, properly closing would be inside a using statement. A bad example could be:

`code`

var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.ToString());

WebResponse myWebResponse = myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
Stream receiveStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
var readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, readEncoding);
response = readStream.ReadToEnd();

readStream.Close();
myWebResponse.Close();
`code`

Comment: Please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably nothing. You'd have to contrive a really weird situation to make this particular gaffe cause a negative effect. However, if you were to put a scenario together, I can think of two potential consequences:

1. The operating system supports a finite number of active network connections. You could exhaust these, and not be able to communicate with any network resources until some of them are completely closed. Also remember that you don't know what else may be going on with the computer: a few bittorrent streams in the background that each take a few hundred connections to other hosts in the swarm, and suddenly you may be closer to that limit than you thought.
2. If the requests are all going to the same resource, that resource may perceive you as a denial of service attacker, and block all future connections.

And really, that's just the start; what I thought of off the top of my head. It's always best to put your toys away.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, if all requests fail without closing, and you create a lot of them, your client will run out of [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) (the ports used for outgoing requests) and fail to connect to any server at all, across all processes. This is bad.

Obviously, the server can run out of resources as well, but not ports. Typically, the ports are gone before any other resources (both client and server), but it all depends on what each request *does*. There is no generic, one-size-fits-all answer.

The real question is: why is your first instinct not to fix this code when you know it's wrong, rather than asking what awful things it could be cooking up? If this code runs into trouble, trust me, *you won't fail to notice this*.

Comment: I'm trying to find out if this situation could explain some high cpu and memory occupation in my web servers.. Can you tell me what are the default timeouts, on client and server?

Comment: All manner of things could be wrong if your server is experiencing high CPU and memory. Knowing specific timeout values won't help you if that's not even the problem -- never assume, this is likely to waste a lot of time without getting you anywhere. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939905/diagnosing-performance-of-asp-net-website-application-pool and work your way from there.